# What PromQL query gives the minimum current value for an arbitrary list of metrics?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have three metrics in Prometheus; let's call them metric1, metric2, and metric3.

I want to determine the minimum of the current values of those three metrics, and I can't figure out the PromQL.

`MIN(metric1)` works; it returns the current value of metric1

I tried `MIN(metric1, metric2, metric3)`, `MIN([metric1, metric2, metric3])`, etc., but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I finally saw this in the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors); if I give the metrics consistent names, I can create an instant vector to match the names by regular expression:

```
min{__name__=~"metric.*"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregate function on a union of your 3 metrics:

```
 MIN(metric1 or metric2 or metric3)
```

That should work. Whether it's a good thing to do depends on what you are really trying to achieve and what your exact use-case is.

[PromQL Operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) 
\
[Working example](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.range_input=1h&g0.expr=MAX(alertmanager_alerts%20or%20alertmanager_cluster_peer_info)&g0.tab=1)